# Extract function source code from existing open source C library

Tags: c, header, macros

I need to extract source code for a function from the existing C library (the library is open source). The problem is that functions are created using macros in header files, and when I write a test project and link the library to it the debugger points me to that header file on 'go to definition' action. I have the source code of the library and I guess i need to build it together with my test code (maybe this is not correct, I am not sure). Any advice on how to proceed, what to use? Thank you.

Comment: Could you be more specific on which library and which debugger you are using, ideally with some [mcve]? -- If a function's definition is put together with "macro magic", there **is** no other function definition for your debugger to show you... you are basically asking for a view on the source as it is after the preprocessor step, i.e. a temporary / internal state -- the debugger cannot show you that.

Comment: The library is blis library https://github.com/flame/blis, I linked it from my solution (In Visual Studio on Windows and in QtCretor and CodeLite on Ubuntu). I included .h file from the library and when I call a function and go to its definition it gives me the location in that .h file where it is created using macros, smt like this: #define GENTPROTR( ctype, ctype_r, ch, chr, opname ) \
\
BLIS_EXPORT_BLIS void PASTEMAC2(ch,opname,EX_SUF) \

Comment: The point is that the debugger can only show you something that is on file. While compiling a debug binary, filename and line number get encoded into the binary, and that is what the debugger uses to "go to definition". In case of a generated function definition, that filename / line number points to the header, where the macro does its generating. What should it do? The expanded version of that function is not "on file"...

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Is there anything I can do to get to the function source code, do you have any advice? I would be very grateful.

Comment: @Mediha if you want to debug the code internally, you can try compiling the source code then adding the pdb to your project. The debugger should then be able to locate the internal code as you step through it. Header files typically shouldn't contain function implementations. But if you are curious about the functions then yes either just look at the source code or compile it and use the pdb

Comment: @Mediha Do you know how macros work?

Answer (score 0):

> I need to extract source code for a function from the existing C library (the library is open source).

Several C compilers are themselves open source. Both [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) and [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/) are (and so is [tinycc](https://github.com/TinyCC/tinycc)). So you legally could improve them (but that could take months of work).

In addition, recent GCC versions (e.g. in july 2020, [GCC 10](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/)) accept [plugins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html). Your GCC plugin could work on some internal GCC representations (e.g. [GIMPLE](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GIMPLE.html), [GENERIC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GENERIC.html)) so will know about functions (even obtained by preprocessor expansion).

You could also consider using some open source static program analyzers,  such as [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/) or [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/).

PS. Take into account [open source license](https://opensource.org/licenses) issues (legal ones). I am not a lawyer (and you might need to ask one, if you mix various software of different open source licenses).

Comment: Lets not start reintroducing links before you've read my message, perhaps?